# На выводе массива выходят странные числа, которые я не вводил

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

господа. При выводе массива поэлементно с помощью цикла, столкнулся с проблемой странного вывода. Перед началом обнулил массив. Попрошу быть толерантнее, ибо я еще учусь.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
int i, n;
int arr[5]; 
int main(void) {
    int arr[5] = { 0 };
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("Введите элемент %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%f", &arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш массив arr целого типа (int), а вводите их как вещественные числа `scanf("%f", &arr[i]);`. Вводите как целые числа `scanf("%d", &arr[i]);`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло!